# Vlc not finding any UPnP devices

Tags: 16.04, vlc, dlna, upnp

I have a minidlna server running in my home and everything worked fine when i updated to ubuntu 16.04 my vlc stopped finding my server. I ran VLC via terminal and got this error when clicking on the UPnP tab. :

```
[00007fdb784db098] upnp services discovery: Initializing libupnp on '(null)' interface
[00007fdb784db098] upnp services discovery error: Initialization failed: UPNP_E_SOCKET_BIND
[00007fdb784db098] core services discovery error: no suitable services discovery module
```

Does someone have any idea how to fix this?

My TV and phone can still find my server.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Disabling ipv6 worked for me.

Solution from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libupnp/+bug/1571199/comments/14) :

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

Comment: Thanks man! It's almost an year that I have this problem and never found the strength to google for it until now!

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer.

You can download a new version of libupnp [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libupnp/+bug/1571199/comments/2)

And install it :

```
cd Downloads
sudo dpkg -i libupnp6_1.6.19+git20160116-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Doing so allowed vlc to display dlna host, but that's all. After that I see in the vlc console the following message: `total jobs = 100, too many jobs`

Comment: Using this lib I was able to browse a local upnp network from VLC 2. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. It doesn't work from VLC 3 but you can open an URL from a video that you browsed from VLC2 (RC display information copy URL).

Answer (score 0):

In my case firewalld was blocking the traffic on the port 1900 tcp/upd.
I enabled it and it worked:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=1900/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=1900/udp
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=home --add-port=1900/tcp
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=home --add-port=1900/udp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Adapt the code to your zone.

Reference:
http://www.vassox.com/infrastructure/networking/opening-a-port-with-firewalld/